# Why is displacement shown in the picture below $y1-y2$ and not $y2-y1$?

Tags: forces, energy, work, conventions, displacement

I am having a hard time understanding why is the displacement in the formula of work shown in the image y1-y2?
Isn't displacement final value - initial value?

[image: Formula for work]

Comment: Recall the definition of displacement as $r_f - r_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction of the $y$ axis is upwards, whereas the weight $w$ acts in the opposite direction, downwards. So the work done on the body by gravity is

$$W_{grav} = -w(y_{end} -y_{start}) = -w(y_2-y_1)=w(y_1-y_2)$$

Comment: Oh, silly me, that makes sense, thanks!